# stopping infinite loop

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, infinite-loop

I am building a social network via code igniter. Upon registration, the potential member get's stored in the db, and their status get's marked to pending. I then send them a confirmation email with a hashed token link. When they hit the link it marks their account as active and takes them to a welcome page that has a sign in.

When I go to the link it sets of an infinite loop and freezes my computer when I'm working on my MAMP. ( or I'm suspicious that it's an infinite loop )

Here is my pertinent code:

auth CONTROLLER that sends the email:

```
function varification_email()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users order by id desc LIMIT 1');
    $token = sha1($user->email.$user->salt).dechex($user->id);
    $domain = "clci.dev/index.php";
    $link = "http://www.".$domain."/account/confirmation/?token=$token";
    foreach ($query->result() as $user)
    {
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('noreply@cysticlife.org', 'CysticLife');
        $this->email->to($user->email); 

        $this->email->subject('Welcome to CysticLife!');
        $this->email->message("Thanks for signing up for CysticLife! To complete the registration process please go to the following web address:\n\n$link\n\n-Your friends at CysticLife\n\nPlease remember to add the cysticlife.org domain to your address book to ensure that you receive your CysticLife e-Notifications as requested.eh");    

        $this->email->send();
}
```

account CONTROLLER that the user is linked back to from the email:

```
public function confirmation() {
    $data['main_content'] = 'account/confirmation';
    $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
    $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('user_model', 'um');
    $login = $this->input->post('submit');


    //IF THE SUBMIT BUTTON IS TRIGGERED THE POST DATA IS SENT TO THE VALIDATE FUNCTION IN THE MODEL VIA VARIABLES CREATED 
    if($login) {
        $user = $this->um->validate(array('email' => $this->input->post('email')));
        if( $user ) {
            // CHECK THE USER'S PASSWORD AGAINST THE ONE FROM THE LOGIN FORM
            if($user->password == $this->encrypt->sha1( $user->salt . $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password')))) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email')
                ));
                $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                redirect('account/dashboard');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->index();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would be surprised that you have a redirect loop. Any decent browsers would stop after a few redirects and output an error message telling you the a loop was detected.

Comment: Can you successfully send an email in a test script?  Perhaps your mail function is failing.

Comment: What's with the open curly brace after the `$link = ...` line in your first piece of code? I wouldn't think that would cause an infinite loop, but it does look like an error...

Comment: yes I have successfully sent emails and had them doing their job and marking 'active' in the db. Just went I start adding the wiring to the form, problems commenced. Perhaps it's that error? thanks.

Comment: that { is for the foreach. perhaps I need to put those variables above them.

Answer (score 0):

### varification_email()

- In v**a**rification_email(), `$user` is used before it is defined. I assume the real code doesn't have this issue.
- Your method for selecting the user in the DB in prone to concurrency errors (wrong user returned).

### confirmation()

- I already had encountered browser hangs because of too large cookies, exceeding something like 4 kB. Have a look at that.
- The problem might be in `user_model->validate()`. Comment out the following of the code and check if it works.